# How to access key itself using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like:

```
  var xx = {'name':'alx','age':12};
```

Now I can read the value of name which is 'alx' as xx[0].name, but how should I retrieve value of 'name' itself? By that, I mean how can I fetch the key at run time?

Comment: First of all, it's not `xx[0].name`, it's `xx.name`. Or, more correct, `xx["name"]`.

Comment: @Felix: why is xx["name"] "more correct" than xx.name?

Comment: @Victor: because you can have keys with special characters, for example `xx["some key"]`. This is valid, yet you can't access it like `xx.some key`. That's why I prefer to always use the `xx["name"]` notation.

Comment: That makes it more flexible, not more correct. It is also less efficient since you have to create a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i in xx) {
    if (xx[i] == "alx") {
        // i is the key
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the other day value is not alx and something else.

Answer (score 1):

modified Code (from Victor) taking into account that you might want to look for any other possible string

```
var search_object = "string_to_look_for";
for (i in xx) {
    if (xx[i] == search_object) {
        // i is the key 
        alert(i+" is the key!!!"); // alert, to make clear which one
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, may b qs is not very clear, but is there a way to retrieve key without even considering the corresponding value

Comment: @Wondering, how will you identify what key you want then?

Comment: @Wondering, pay attention to the comment in that code.  // i is the key

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for associative arrays in Javascript. A quick google search suggests the following:

Read this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

and especially this section http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html#link5