# How can I make my json object's field name a value with in an object array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

This is my object:

```
{Mary : 'Engineer', Jane : 'Doctor'}
```

I want to turn it into this format:

```
{[Name: 'Marry', Occupation: 'Engineer'], [Name: 'Jane', Occupation: 'Doctor']}
```

How can I do it with javascript?

Comment: The syntax of your second example is wrong: it would have to be `[{name: 'Mary', occupation: 'Engineer'}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = [];
var i = "";
for (i in yourJSON) {
    // i is the key
    result.push({Name: i, Occupation: yourJSON[i]});
}
```

from [How to access key itself using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942911/how-to-access-key-itself-using-javascript)

greetings

Comment: You should declare `i` as a `var` before you use it (you're using a global right now).

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the first object and place the elements where you want them.

```
var obj = {Mary : 'Engineer', Jane : 'Doctor'};
var people = [];

for(var name in obj){
    var occ = obj[name];

    people.push({Name: name, Occupation: occ});
}
```

The example object you show in your question uses invalid syntax.  What you want is an *array* of objects, that's what this code does.

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop over the keys in your data and make a new object for each, with the name and occupation properties. Something like:

```
function makeNameOccupation(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map(c => {
    return {name: c, occupation: data[c]};
  });
}

console.log(makeNameOccupation({Mary : 'Engineer', Jane : 'Doctor'}))
```

For each key in the original object (the person's name) you map that into an object with the `name` and `occupation` properties. Since you have the name (as the key), you can fetch the occupation from the original object with ease, and build the new record.

That can be minified, if you're into that sort of thing, into:

```
return Object.keys(data).map(c => ({name: c, occupation: data[c]}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
var data = {
  "Mary": 'Engineer',
  "Jane": 'Doctor'
}

var res = Object.keys(data).map(function(name) {
  return {
    "Name": name,
    "Occupation": data[name]
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't valid, you want an *array* of *objects*:

```
[{Name: 'Marry', Occupation: 'Engineer'}, {Name: 'Jane', Occupation: 'Doctor'}]
```

And you can do so like:

```
var people = []
var person = {Name: 'Jane', Occupation: 'Doctor'};
people.push(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have an object that looks like this

```
var originalPeopleObj = {Mary : 'Engineer', Jane : 'Doctor'}
```

What you want to do, is get the list of people's names inside your object.

```
var names = Object.keys(originalPeopleObj);
```

This will create an array of people names

```
names = ["Mary", "Jane"];
```

Now, you have to map those names to their occupations inside the `originalPeopleObj`

```
var newPeople = [];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length ; i++) {
     var peopleObj = {};
     peopleObj[i].name = names[i];
     peopleObj[i].occupation = originalPeopleObj[names[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the keys of the object and build a new array of objects.

```js
var object = { Mary: 'Engineer', Jane: 'Doctor' },
    result = Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
        return { Name: key, Occupation: object[key] };
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of es5, the key doesn't adapt the datatype automatically, the logic needs to be as follows:
 `var object = { Mary: 'Engineer', Jane: 'Doctor' }; result = Object.keys(object).map(function (key) { return { Name: key, Occupation: object[key as keyof datatype] }; });`